# Align several texts in the Container

Tags: flutter, alignment

I have now tried to design my container with various widgets, unfortunately I am unable to continue with many optimization attempts. So I wanted to ask how you would approach it.
I would like to design a container as follows.
[image: Stack -> Container -> Row -> Column -> Align -> Text ..]
Maybe someone can tell me how a structure like this looks best. I have tried different structures such as

```
ListView-> Stack -> Container -> Row -> Column -> Align -> Text ..
```

every time i fail to align the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Spacer` to take all the remaining space in your `Column`. Try this:

```
 Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 12),
        Text("Facebook"),
        Spacer(),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("Sales:"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("200Mio."),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("HeadQuarters:"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("New York"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("Employee:"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Text("200Tsd."),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

Here is a video discussing about `Spacer`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FJgd7QN1zI

Structure it like this: Horizontal ListView.builder -> Container with a (IMPORTANT) -> set/fixed height (define your height) and border outline radius -> Then place the code above inside the Container.